# XORG Dual Graphic Card Setup NVIDIA

Tags: linux, xorg, nvidia, xinerama

I asked a related question on Stack Exchange and it seems that nobody understands anything there, so I will format this question for here and maybe have better luck.

I am trying to setup 2 NVIDIA GT 610 graphics cards both with 2 DVI, 1 Micro HDMI and 1 VGA output, and 4 27" monitors. I only want to use the 2 DVI outputs on each card to span all the monitors which I already have working. I have two monitors on one card and the other two monitors on the second card. My issue is that I want each monitor to act as it's own monitor (not Xinerama style) where if I maximize and application it does not span across the two monitors that belong to a single card, or I also do not want my dock to span two monitors as well. I know this is a Xinerama feature which works now (undesired), but I would like it to work such as it would without Xinerama on a two monitor, single graphics card setup (maximize to one monitor & dock spans only one monitor & drag across monitors). Here is my current configuration.

I've spent a lot of time reading about it but I cannot find anything that helps me with this particular configuration.

Thanks in advance!

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option      "DontZap"       "no"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices"        "false"
    Option      "AutoEnableDevices"     "false"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen  1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen  2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
    Screen  3  "Screen3" RightOf "Screen2"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "MouseW0" "SendCoreEvents"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "evdev"
    Option     "Device" "/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:7:1.0-event-kbd"
    Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
    Option "xkb_model" "evdev"
    Option "xkb_layout" "us"
    Option "GrabDevice" "on"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "evdev"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mouse0"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "MouseW0"
    Driver         "evdev"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-PixArt_USB_Optical_Mouse-event-mouse"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

# graphics card 1 slot 0
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

# graphics card 1 slot 1
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:1"
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"
EndSection

# graphics card 2 slot 0
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"
EndSection

# graphics card 2 slot 1
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:1"
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Samsung"
    ModelName      "Samsung S27B350"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Samsung"
    ModelName      "Samsung S27B350"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Samsung"
    ModelName      "Samsung S27A550H"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Anchor Communications Inc"
    ModelName      "Anchor Communications Inc VS278"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
            Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
            Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
            Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
            Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Guess not here either.